# Passing the row id on select to the JavaScript file in java

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://holt59.github.io/datatable/

I have used the this link for filtration and pagination of my table. Earlier i was using the
        **$('tr[data-href]').on("click", function() {
         document.location = $(this).data('href');** 
JavaScript code for selecting the row and getting the id , now its not working when i included the js file. please help me to get the dynamic selection of rows.

Comment: Can you please explain what you want to do!

Comment: I am selecting the row and getting the row id on select and i am displaying the details related to that row, i am using javascript to achieve this.
I have used the above link for page navigation and filtration. but i am not able to achieve the row selection.somewhere i have to fit the row id.. i am not getting how to do as i am new to javascript. plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably destroying and re-adding the rows which removes your event handler. Use event delegation.

```
$(document).on("click", 'tr[data-href]', function() { 
    document.location = $(this).data('href'); 
});
```

You can move the listening location closer to the row

```
$("#tableId").on("click", "tr...
```

Comment: So does the datatable remove the data attribute from the row? If so, you are going to have to find a different way to identify the row.